# Good book on quantum probability

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, complex-geometry, quantum-information

Who can suggest me a book on quantum probability?
I'm mostly interested in its geometric aspects (complex projective space, Fubini-Study...).
I have a background in quantum mechanics and differential geometry.

Thanks!

Comment: Quantum Probability for Probabilistics, Paul Meyer.

Comment: If you want an approach via operator theory you can try Operator Algebras and Quantum Statistical Mechanics by Bratteli and Robinson.